original sanskrit verse from Jñānārṇava
I have come across a text from Jñānārṇava, it is a treatise on Jain Yoga in roughly 2200 Sanskrit verses composed by Śubhacandra. The meaning of the verse is
Fool, there is no embodied soul in the three worlds for whom the noose of Yama will not stretch on their neck

I am looking for the original Sanskrit verse, if someone can point me to original verse or help me how to find it, it would be really helpful.
